# Where should a Django homepage template and view exist in a large-scale project?

Tags: python, django

On a large-scale Django project, where should the homepage template and view exist within the project structure?

**In its own app** (ex: homepage app)?

**Some other app** (ex: accounts)?

**At the project-level** putting the template in a "templates" directory and the view somewhere?

**Somewhere else**?

Is there a most frequent answer to this question?

**Definitions:**

1. Large-scale is defined as let's say 15 apps
2. The homepage content is mostly static now, with plans to get more dynamic as the project evolves

**Assumption**: project structure strategy is dependent on the size of the project.

Comment: I had about three to four apps when I was working on a Django project and had templates for each app in its own `templates` folder. Made it easier for me to make edits and was less clutter.

Comment: @ClockSlave Thanks. Yeah, I definitely intend to use `'APP_DIRS' : True` and have app-specific templates in the apps themselves. I'm just not sure the most common approach for the homepage.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach in my opinion implement everything as separate app because of code re-use. You can create app called "landing" with templates folder inside with nested "landing" directory what's how Django might find you templates automatically from GenericViews for example.

```
yourproject/
    landing/
         templates/
             landing/
                 index.html
        urls.py
        models.py
        views.py
```